# Hole Filling methods takes over 20 minutes

Tags: c++, cgal

When trying to fill holes in a mesh with a border that is highly complex, the application takes 20 minutes in the hole filling call.

It can be any of the calls shown [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__hole__filling__grp.html#gaaa1bfaf9a57dea8b6c71168a18f9b6eb).

The code I'm using is this:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("V:/tobehealed2.off");
    Triangle_mesh mesh;
    input >> mesh;

    //////////////
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> indices(mesh.num_faces());
    std::vector<Point_3> vertices(mesh.num_vertices());

    int i = 0;
    for (auto& p : mesh.points()) {
        vertices[i++] = p;
    }

    i = 0;
    for (auto& f : mesh.faces()) {
        std::vector<int> triangle(3);
        int j = 0;
        for (auto v : mesh.vertices_around_face(mesh.halfedge(f))) {
            triangle[j++] = v;
        }

        indices[i++] = triangle;
    }

    mesh.clear();

    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::repair_polygon_soup(vertices, indices);
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::orient_polygon_soup(vertices, indices);

    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh(vertices, indices, mesh);

    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::keep_largest_connected_components(mesh, 1);

    bool hasHoles = true;

    std::vector<face_descriptor> face_out;
    std::vector<vertex_descriptor> vertex_out;

    while (hasHoles) {
        hasHoles = false;

        for (auto& hh : mesh.halfedges()) {
            if (mesh.is_border(hh)) {
                hasHoles = true;
                CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_and_refine_hole(mesh, hh, std::back_inserter(face_out), std::back_inserter(vertex_out));
                break;
            }
        }

        face_out.clear();
        vertex_out.clear();
    }

    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::keep_largest_connected_components(mesh, 1);
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::remove_isolated_vertices(mesh);

    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::remove_self_intersections(mesh);

    CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification::Count_stop_predicate<Triangle_mesh> stop(60000);
    int r = CGAL::Surface_mesh_simplification::edge_collapse(mesh, stop);
    mesh.collect_garbage();

    std::ofstream out2("V:/healed.off");
    out2 << mesh;
}
```

Application takes over 20 minutes in the call to `triangulate_and_refine_hole`.

Tested model is available for download here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t2dwJBs5vNpg2jLOVprHEY-8tCHvCErK/view?usp=sharing

My goal is just to be able to check beforehand if the model has a hole so complex the closing of it will take several minutes, so I can skip the hole filling attempt. Also, if there is a way to exit the function call after some threshold time it would be nice.

The size of the model doesn't matter so much. If I use a mesh 3 times larger, it can fill a not-so-complex-hole in just a few seconds.

Comment: Your input is correct; there's a specific geometric configuration that seems to be difficult to treat, and we will look into how we could potentially improve that. In the meantime, the last step of your algorithm is a simplification, so you could improve things by simplifying before filling the hole. Admittedly this could in theory create a non-simple border, but it doesn't happen on your data. Here is your example adapted: https://gist.github.com/MaelRL/657d21493396fb0920f685b861c70b55, which runs about instantly.

Comment: It appears that the 5.0.2 which I'm using does not have the `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::experimental::remove_self_intersections`. Is it available on 5.1?

Comment: `remove_self_intersections()` was erroneously in the namespace `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing` (no `experimental`) in CGAL 5.0 despite not being documented, see https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/blob/releases/CGAL-5.0-branch/Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/repair.h#L2912. It has been moved to `::experimental` for in the upcoming 5.1 release (already the case in master). It was also made a bit stronger for 5.1.

Answer (score 0):

> Also, if there is a way to exit the function call after some threshold time it would be nice.

What always works is to start the task in another thread and monitor that thread, killing it if necessary after some time.

Really wouldn't be a pretty solution though. CGAL is still a maintained library, so fairly sure you just povide it some incorrect data. Or are you sure at all that it actually hangs up?
36Mb is quite a solid size for a model and hole-fixing is a task that grows with model complexity if I recall right.

EDIT:
Ah well, if you can afford to wait in general for 20 mintes before having a repaired model, threading is the way to go. It will just run in the background.
if you cannot afford that it takes so long, well, then it is not so easy. Either you find some significantly better implementation (not that likely), or you will have to do some trade offs. Either simplifying the model or living with less correct hole fixes (assuming there are some heuristic algorithms for this task).

Comment: Yes. I edited 5 minutes ago saying that the application finished the process successfully after 20 minutes. I don't think the size of the mesh matters that much, since I got holes fixed in meshes 3 times larger in less than 10 seconds. What counts is the complexity of the hole, which I don't know how to measure prior entering the process.

Comment: Edited too, but hmm, I see. Fear I don't know how one would go about assuming this complexity.